# How to open Cmd with selenium?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, cmd

Wanted to know if it's possible to open other applications with selenium with python, for instance cmd.
Ive tried doing web drivers and everything works fine.

Comment: You can use Python to open cmd, Selenium can not do anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know selenium library but if you want to use cmd commands in python use this

```
import os
os.system("msg * Hi")
```

If you want to open cmd from python use this

```
import os
os.startfile('program.exe')
```